# Figlet text font size?

Tags: html, text, figlet

So i recently downloaded (http://www.figlet.org/) the figlet application to create big text our of digits and symbols for html themes.

I finally managed to create my big text message using the 'Roman.flf' font and saved it to my computer (always a '.txt' file)

So then i copied and pasted the text from the '.txt' file into my tumblr html but apparently the text is too big so it gets messed up and you can't even read the text in my html. And I'm trying to make it as a figlet message as a theme credit for my theme.

Does anyone know how to change the font size or size of the figlet text in the JAVe program?

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII art for normal figlet fonts is done in only one size. Your best bet is changing the font size of the text you're using to display the output. Also, browsers like to collapse multiple white spaces into a single white space, so you may want to make sure that also isn't happening.